# I want to loop my code in python for Raspberry pi

Tags: python, loops

here is my code and I don't know how loop it.Thanks to help me out!!

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
os.system('clear')

#Clear Fenetre et import

print "Test programme";

#Splash


Bacvar = raw_input("Code pour Bac:")

Prodvar = raw_input("Code pour Produit:")
code = str(Bacvar)+str(Prodvar)

#Entree de variables

print code
with open("test.txt", "wt") as out_file:
 out_file.write(code + "\n")


#Export vers txt
```

So basically the program is connected to a raspberry pi and a barcode scanner. The user will scan a box. I want that data to be exported as "code" to a txt file and after the file has been exported, To loop to the beginning of the code. I tried a `while True:` but it didn't seem to work work.

So when a code is exported to my txt file by scanning an item. The second code which is generated should be exported to the same txt but at the second line and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens now when you use `while true`?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use **exception** and the event `KeyboardInterrupt` for example.

```
try:
    while True:
        #your code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
```

When you will hit a keyboard key, you will exit your infinite loop. Now does it work on Raspberry Pi with an I/O input... It should but keep us aware ^^

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
import os
```

os.system('clear')

## Clear Fenetre et import

print "Test programme";

## Splash

while True:

```
    Bacvar = raw_input("Code pour Bac:")
    Prodvar = raw_input("Code pour Produit:")
    code = str(Bacvar)+str(Prodvar)
    print code

    with open('export.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(code)
```

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

And when i execute it i got this:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./test3.py
  File "./test3.py", line 21
    f.write(code)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Thanks to help!